# Can this be done with Blender? Web rendering

Tags: python

I have never used Blender so this question might not even make sense. Essentially, I'd like to make a web-app that takes a 3D file of an interior space present in the website, renders it in Blender from a specific view-point (passed in the data), and displays the output image back on the website. Can this be done with the Python API for Blender?

I'm relatively new to coding in general. Any suggestions as to how to proceed with achieving this would really be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible to do this, however if you're relatively new to coding I would suggest starting on something a little easier to chew. You would need to write some sort of program itself that resided on your server and you could communicate with via Javascript or maybe Python and Django on the backend. That program could run Blender in the background, render the file, return the file back through the server and spit it onto the webpage. This is all fairly complex and there would be a fair few moving parts to wrangle.

Comment: There are also options for 3D rendering specifically for web apps like [three.js](https://threejs.org/), or [WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org/) that are probably a bit more streamlined. Probably not quite as fully featured as Blender Cycles or even EEVEE but, it depends on what you're tryinh to accomplish I guess.

Comment: @Jakemoyo thank you for response! If the web-app is successful and has a few concurrent users, will one have to use a render farm (which has an API) like Renderstreet to do the renders? How do I go about hiring a freelancer for this project (creating the entire web-application)? Which skillsets should I look out for? Will this be a complex thing for a relatively seasoned developer or an easy one?

Comment: In terms of 3D rendering for three.js, are you referring to tools like [clara.io](https://clara.io/)? They seem to allow scripting. @Jakemoyo

Comment: I suppose, I think clara seems to be a browser app that utilizes three.js to power it's backend. Like think bpy is to Blender as three.js is to clara. From what I can tell. As far as hiring a freelancer Idk, I know my way around web-dev concepts but i am not seasoned by any means. So it's hard for me to say how difficult it would be. I can at least say it's not trivial. Not something any dumdum could put together in a day or two. But it all depends on the scope of your project really. If you have a preset list of models and want to render those only it might be easy. feel free to DM.